# bash, get part of file limited by 2 strings based on grep

Tags: bash, alias

Here is input file (3 parts divided by `##`).

```
## some info 1
aaa
bbb
ccc

## some info 2
ddd
eee
fff

## some info 3
ggg
hhh
iii
```

I need get one or more parts of file based on search words based on paremeters behind script.

Example.

**IN**

`find-part-of-file.sh hhh aaa`

**OUT**

```
## some info 1
aaa
bbb
ccc

## some info 3
ggg
hhh
iii
```

And one little question, is possible use more than 1 variables `$1` in aliases from `.bashrc`? Because when I am using for example alias with script with more variables, alias "join" both inputs to last variable.

```
alias test-env="echo var1 = $1 , var2 = $2"

hosek@dell:~$ test-env aaa
var1 = , var2 = aaa
hosek@dell:~$ test-env aaa bbb
var1 = , var2 = aaa bbb
hosek@dell:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use positional parameters at all with aliases; your example only *appears* to assign a value whereas in reality both `$1` and `$2` are expanding to empty values then any "parameters" are being appended, as you can verify using `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ alias test-env="echo var1 = $1 , var2 = $2"
+ alias 'test-env=echo var1 =  , var2 = '

$ test-env aaa
+ echo var1 = , var2 = aaa
var1 = , var2 = aaa
```

If you want to pass parameters, use a shell function instead:

```
unalias test-env
test-env () { echo "echo var1 = $1 , var2 = $2"; }
```

For your main question, I'd suggest using awk in *paragraph mode" rather than grep ex. with GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -v RS= -v pats='aaa|hhh' '$0 ~ pats {ORS=RT; print}' file
## some info 1
aaa
bbb
ccc

## some info 3
ggg
hhh
iii
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `grep`, it can be done like so:

```
grep -Pzo "##([^#]+)(\baaa\b|\bhhh\b)([^#]+)" file
```

- That will start at each `##`, match `aaa` or `hhh` and print the whole matching block befor the next `#`.
- `-Pzo` will enable using Perl-compatible regular expressions with `-P`, enable multi-line with `-z` and print only the matched parts with `-o`.
- `\b` specifies the word boundaries. It matches all the characters surrounded by it at once as a whole word which prevents matching words in the file with partial matching characters i.e. exact word no more and no less.